Could you make a fire torch with electricity?
Similar to a blowtorch, is there a way to generate a flame without using gas or liquid fuel(like butane, propane, etc)?

(source)
For example I'm thinking about those portable air heaters, could one make a flame with some device like that?

(source)

"...is there a way to generate a flame without using gas or liquid fuel..." You can use solid fuel. Like a matchstick...

For the record, this isn't a bad physics question. It could be reworded in a physics context (for fear of sacrificing the OP's intent, I will let them make the edit), but what's being asked is "why is fuel the necessary component of a blowtorch, why can't electricity be used". Sort of the same question that got asked of internal combustion engines in cars.

Google "plasma torch." Technically, it's not a flame, but for practical purposes, it might as well be one.

Arc welders do a good job at it.

No.
Yes, you can generate very high temperatures by causing dielectric breakdown of air to form plasma, but this requires unimaginably high voltages. At ~3 kV/mm, air is a very good dielectric insulator and will require enormous voltages to break down even a small volume of air to heat it up to the required temperatures. High enough that the device would probably not be safe to hold; even a small fault in that circuit could kill the user.
The nice thing about fuel is that it just burns in air, no voltage or anything required. Sure, you need a spark to start up the fire, but once that's going it's going and no energy input is necessary other than fuel after that point. With electricity, massive energy input is required, and putting something like that in your hand is going to create various problems, including potential circuit faults as well as just resistive heating. Even with good commercially-available conductors, i.e. gold and silver, the heating that would be produced would be significant and could be dangerous. (I haven't done the calculations to check that, but if you're running enough electricity through the air to heat it to hundreds of degrees above room temperature, I assume that you're also gonna be dealing with very high power throughput near at least one resistive component in the device.)
Portable air heaters have it good because they don't heat the air by much. It might feel like a lot to our oversensitive and unscientific human bodies, but if you heat a small area/room by a few degrees, not only does that require potentially less energy but also dissipates slower because the temperature gradient with the surroundings is lower. This means that the portable air heater can supply a lower heat source over a longer period to gradually heat up the area by a few degrees, whereas your electric blowtorch will have to continuously pour a lot of heat into a small area to heat it by hundreds of degrees, most of which will dissipate instantly as soon as the power is interrupted/stopped.

A flame is the chemical reaction of fuel combining with oxygen. The reaction is energetic enough that atoms are kicked into excited states. They give off light when they drop back to ground states.
Without fuel, there can be no reaction and hence no flame.
